# What is a "class attribute" variable and how to use simple linear regression on these variables?

Tags: regression

I'm using a database that contais the following variables:

Wife's religion: 0 = not islamic , 1 = islamic (binary variable)

Contraceptive method used: 1 = not used, 2 = long term, 3 = short term (class attribute)

I wanted to see how the wife's religion relates to use in contraceptive methods using a simple linear regression. But how to relate these two variables since they are not numerical and what is "class attribute" ?

Comment: You do not need can not use linear regression. Just construct a 3x2 tables, perform Fisher's exact test or Pearson chi-square test, get several percents.